# In Python print any None values in a dict, error, too many values to unpack

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3.x I want to print out any values that are **null/None** in a directory. This is what I have tried:

```
dict = {
            'USER': self.user,
            'SUBJECT': self.sub,
            'BODY': self.body,
        }
null_keys = [value for key, value in dict if key[value] is None]
        if null_keys:
            print('You have NULL value(s) for...{}'.format(null_keys)
```

However, I get this error:

**ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)**

why?

Comment: `value for key, value in dict.items()` maybe?! is this code copy from some where else?

Comment: @Arman No, this was just my first attempt at an exercise to find the best way to output the key of any null values in a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works, try this:

```
d = dict({
"a": None,
"b": 2,
"c": None
})

null_keys = list()

for k,v in d.items(): 
  if(d.get(k) is None):
    null_keys.extend(k)

for i in null_keys:
  print('You have NULL value(s) for...{}'.format(i))
```

Comment: Variable names should use snake_case. CamelCase should be reserved for class names

Answer (score 2):

use 
    dict.iteritems() whenever you are trying to iterate over a dictionary

In python3 use:

dict.items() to iterate.